# How can I see what I got a Nice Question badge for (Area 51)?

Tags: feature-request, questions, area-51, badges

How can I easily see what I got a Nice Question badge for. I clicked on the Nice Question link, expecting to go to the appropriate question but actually I went to a link with all people who recently go the badge.

Instead I'd like to go directly to the appropriate question.

The only way I could work it out was to go to my reputation tab and look at the top questions. This works OK for a short time period but I imagine it'd be a problem if I had to hunt through several questions.

Is there an easier way?

BTW - this question may apply to other forums and / or badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature in the engine.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/improvements-to-badge-system/

It is unlikely this feature will be back-ported to Area 51, though. Sorry :(

Comment: shame (why not?). Thanks for the response.